# Apache poi 3.10. HSSFFONT setColor doesnt work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to have cells with white colored font but they always appear black, this is my code:

```
HSSFCellStyle estiloCabecera = wb.createCellStyle();
estiloCabecera.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
estiloCabecera.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

HSSFFont fuenteCabecera = wb.createFont();
fuenteCabecera.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
fuenteCabecera.setFontName("Arial");
fuenteCabecera.setColor((short)HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
//fuenteCabecera.setColor(HSSFFont.COLOR_RED);
estiloCabecera.setFont(fuenteCabecera);

Row rowCabeceraTabla = sheet.createRow((short)3);
Cell celda = rowCabeceraTabla.createCell(0);
celda.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Id pregunta"));
celda.setCellStyle(estiloCabecera);
```

I dont understand why, and I have tried everything I can think of. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: When I use your code (with minor modifications, as I get compile errors otherwise), I get a black cell with white font. So this is what you want, right? ... Can you check if your classes get updated (because of the compile errors)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried with poi 3.9 and still get the same: a black rectangle in the cell...:S What error do you get? I want the letters in white, yes, but no way..¬¬

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in my comment, your example works for me, i.e. I get a black cell with white text.

The rectangle(s) instead of the text normally points out, that you've got an encoding problem or the font is not supporting the chars. Instead of "Arial" can you try to use "Arial Unicode MS"?

I'm posting my code as an answer just for further reference ... and will update it, if we found out new details, which could solve your issue ...

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;


public class ForegroundColor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

        CellStyle estiloCabecera = wb.createCellStyle();
        estiloCabecera.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        estiloCabecera.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        Font fuenteCabecera = wb.createFont();
        fuenteCabecera.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
        fuenteCabecera.setFontName("Arial");
        fuenteCabecera.setColor((short)HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        //fuenteCabecera.setColor(HSSFFont.COLOR_RED);
        estiloCabecera.setFont(fuenteCabecera);

        Row rowCabeceraTabla = sheet.createRow((short)3);
        Cell celda = rowCabeceraTabla.createCell(0);
        celda.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Id pregunta"));
        celda.setCellStyle(estiloCabecera);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("color.xls"); 
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know what to say... i have spent more than 4 hours with this problem...and i was setting black font color after setting it white (copy/paste ¬¬)... Sorry for the incovenience :S I feel really dumb!